# Heroku: IOError - HTTP session already opened: when saving Amazon S3

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ioerror

Sometimes my heroku app has IOError (HTTP session already opened) when the app writing an image file Amazon S3.
I have no idea why this happens sometimes.
Does this depends on server capacity? Actually my app runs on only one Worker of Heroku.

```
app[web.1]: IOError - HTTP session already opened:
app[web.1]:     /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:623:in `start'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sauberia-aws-s3-0.6.2.1254423624/lib/aws/s3/connection.rb:53:in `request'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sauberia-aws-s3-0.6.2.1254423624/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:72:in `request'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sauberia-aws-s3-0.6.2.1254423624/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:101:in `put'
app[web.1]:     /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sauberia-aws-s3-0.6.2.1254423624/lib/aws/s3/object.rb:249:in `store'
app[web.1]:     /app/server.rb:601:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     /app/server.rb:556:in `each'
app[web.1]:     /app/server.rb:556:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Solved.
The cause was my heroku stack is cedar and an app server run as Webrick!
Generally speaking, Webrick is not enough powerful, and I should use Thin.
The following document helped me.(Refer to "Choose app server")

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration

Comment: It would be awesome if you would copy your comment to answer and mark it as accepted.